# While replacing using regex, how do I keep a part of the matched string?

Tags: regex

I am trying to replace all `,` between two digits with a `.` in order to create valid SQL statements from certain raw data.

Damn the Americans and their wrong (vice versa) use of `,` and `.` as delimiters in numbers that foce me to do this...

I figured the easiest way to get this done is by using Notepad++ and some RegEx magic. First part is done, I've got a solid match on the strings that I want to replace by using this statement:

`\d{1}[\,]{1}\d{1}`

However, I still need to create the statement that I want the matches to be replaced with. To do that, I need to keep a part of the matched string (the digits) and only replace the comma between the digits with a full stop.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Please avoid using unnecessary phrases such as "..Damn the ...".  There is no need to pass judgement on conventions used by various countries

Comment: As an American, I feel insulted by your comment. What dot and period are used for depend on whether your region adopting the British or the French system of notions. Wanna see something even more distinctive? In India 1 million is written as `1,00,00,000`. I guess that's wrong for you too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not very particular about using Notepad++, and you have text that is not very big, you can use this website: http://www.regexpal.com/

You can search using regex:

```
/(\d+),(\d+)/g
```

And replace using below:

```
$1.$2
```